# Is magnitude operator |..| linear or non-linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am working on a problem in electrical engineering where I have to take the magnitude square of the following term as given in the picture below [image]

I have to take the magnitude square of the equation no -4 which is complex, so that is going to be a^2 +b^2 + 2 a*b or just a^2 + b^2?

[image]

as I read somewhere above picture

Comment: Is $(3+4)^2$ equal to $3^2 + 4^2$ or is it $3^2 + 2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 + 4^2$?

Comment: That is what I am asking. They are obviously not equal @MartinR

Comment: @MartinR Question has an edit now, maybe you get it

Comment: Try to calculate the three expressions in Martin Rs answer!

Comment: What exactly is the question here? In general, $|x+y|^2=|x|^2+2x\cdot y+|y|^2$, but if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, then $x\cdot y=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but here goes.The RHS of equation 4 is of the form $|z_1 + z_2|^2$, where $z_1, z_2$ are complex numbers. Let $*$ denote complex conjugation. Note that $|z|^2=z^*\cdot z$. Writing it out as follows

$$|z_1 + z_2|^2 = (z_1 + z_2)^* \cdot(z_1 + z_2)= z_1^*z_1+z_1^*z_2+z_2^*z_1+z_2^*z_2$$
$$= |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+z_1^*z_2+z_2^*z_1$$

After which you plug in the terms $z_1, z_2$